# calling callback function before rest of code (Javascript D3)

Tags: javascript, url, callback, d3.js

Basically what I want to do is get string result from a URL. the result I get when I use my browser on the URL can be as simple as the string "word dog cat dog".

I'm trying to use the following:

```
var textwords;
d3.text(myUrl, function(data) {
 textwords = data;
});
```

and later on using `textwords` somehow in the following lines, but I can't of course because the callback function executes after all other code.

is there any way (other than putting all of the following code inside the callback function) I can manage to use `textwords` after it gets the data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the short answer is no. The long answer is also no, but you could make things look a little nicer by using [jQuery's Defferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/). There is a really good introduction [here](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/)